# issues with view on Multiplatform app for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, multiplatform

Why is my Multiplatform app looks like this in macOS but it look fine on the iOS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFoSB.jpg)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu4NN.jpg)

```
import SwiftUI

struct listsView: View {

@State private var isPresented: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button {
            isPresented = true
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .font(.system(size: 128))
                Text("Create your first list")
            }
            .foregroundColor(.primary)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented) {
            addNewListView { newListName, colorCode in
                //Save
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

I found a solution on reddit
just add a .buttonStyle(.plain)

thanks for everyone who tried to help

Comment: In iOS you have a well defined outer frame for SwiftUI to work with but not on macOS where the window can be any size. use `.frame(...)` on your `VStack` to see a fixed or min size

Comment: still doesn't work the square frame got bigger but the plus icon is still as it is

Comment: as @JoakimDanielson said try add a frame to the Vstack but like that              .frame(minWidth: 800, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 1000,maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center) where you define the smallest window you should work on it and make it expandable

Comment: same issue there is a big box(frame) around it but the plus icon is still only half of it shown 

i don't know how to share a photo in a comment to show you

Comment: add a frame also to the Image like that Image(systemName: "plus").frame(width:100,height:100,alignment:.center) and it should work @Hamza

Comment: tried that nothing happened 